# mtpro2 numbers in small size in mathematical formula has different shape

Tags: mtpro

I'm using LaTeX with MathTime Pro 2 fonts (package `mtpro2`). In normal size

```
123 $123$
```

gives two numbers with the same shape. Instead

```
{\small 123 $123$}
```

gives  two smaller numbers with different shapes. The second is slightly larger and fat.

I would like to have again two smaller numbers with the same shape. This is what is obtained using e.g., `mathptmx`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't set Times as text font, you'll get different digits in text and math.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tgtermes} % or mathptmx
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}

\begin{document}

123 $123$

{\small 123 $123$}

\end{document}
```

[image]